# PHP & XML Read element by attribute value

Tags: php, xml

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<entries>
    <response>
        <category>client</category>
        <action>Greeting</action>
        <code>1000</code> 
        <msg>Your Connection with API Server is Successful</msg> 
        <resData> 
            <data name="svDate">2010-10-10 02:27:14</data> 
        </resData>
    </response>

    <response>
        <category>client</category>
        <action>Login</action>
        <code>1000</code>
        <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
        <value>L116:no value</value>
    </response>

    <response>
        <category>domain</category>
        <action>InfoDomain</action>
        <code>1000</code>
        <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
        <value>L125:no value</value>
        <resData>
            <data name="domain">google.com</data>
            <data name="crDate">2004-12-16</data>
            <data name="exDate">2013-12-16</data>
        </resData>
    </response>
</entries>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$domain = $xml->response[2]->resData[0]->data[0];
$crdate = $xml->response[2]->resData[0]->data[1];
$exdate = $xml->response[2]->resData[0]->data[2];
```

With the above code i can get the values.
But how can i get the values by attribute value?

For example i want to get the values with something like this:

```
$domain = $xml->response[2]->resData[0]->data["domain"];
$crdate = $xml->response[2]->resData[0]->data["crdate"];
$exdate = $xml->response[2]->resData[0]->data["exdate"];
```

One more question.

If i have two elements with the same name?
For example i would like to parse the dns. How could i do it?

The xml code is like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<entries>
    <response>
        <category>client</category>
        <action>Greeting</action>
        <code>1000</code> 
        <msg>Your Connection with API Server is Successful</msg> 
        <resData> 
            <data name="svDate">2010-10-10 02:27:14</data> 
        </resData>
    </response>

    <response>
        <category>client</category>
        <action>Login</action>
        <code>1000</code>
        <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
        <value>L116:no value</value>
    </response>

    <response>
        <category>domain</category>
        <action>InfoDomain</action>
        <code>1000</code>
        <msg>Command completed successfully</msg>
        <value>L125:no value</value>
        <resData>
            <data name="domain">google.com</data>
            <data name="crDate">2004-12-16</data>
            <data name="exDate">2013-12-16</data>
            <data name="dns">ns1.google.com</data>
          <data name="dns">ns2.google.com</data>
        </resData>
    </response>
</entries>
```

As you can see the ns1 and ns2 have the same name. name="dns".
How can i parse each one in a different variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `element["attribute"]` syntax, `attribute` is the name of an attribute on the `element`. It is not the value of some randomly chosen attribute belonging to an element.

The example below creates an array containing a mapping for the `data` elements of `name` attribute value to text value.

```
$data = array();
foreach ($xml->response[2]->resData->data as $d) {
    $data[strtolower($d['name'])] = (string) $d;
}

// Now you can access the values via $data['domain'], $data['crdate'], etc.
```

---

Nick, your code expects XML structured like:

```
<resData>
    <data domain="google.com" crdate="2004-12-16" exdate="2013-12-16" />
</resData>
```

---

**Edit due to question change**

In a marvelous dose of eating my own words, due to the change in the question an XPath approach would be more appropriate (don't you love OPs who do that?).

You can easily get an array of the `name="dns"` elements with a basic XPath expression.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$dns = $xml->xpath('response[category="domain"]/resData/data[@name="dns"]');
```

Comment: I wont downvote but I think an XPath solution would be less cumbersome and in general more appropriate because it operates on the tree itself and not some copy. Copying the values into the array is just a waste of memory. Any changes the OP will do to the tree after the copy wont be reflected in it either and vice versa. Writing the values back to XML requires extra effort then.

Comment: As we discussed on chat, I don't think an XPath solution would be less cumbersome, nor more appropriate. Changes to the tree are a non-issue as the OP is only reading, until the question changes I don't care about the tree... nor should you.  Feel free to provide your less cumbersome, more appropriate XPath solution for the OP to choose which he prefers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) to to do queries against your XML, e.g.

```
$entries = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$dataElements = $entries->xpath('/entries/response/resData/data[@name="dns"]');
foreach ($dataElements as $dataElement) {
    echo $dataElement;
}
```

The above XPath finds all `<data>` elements with a `name` attribute of "dns" that are direct children of the given element hierarchy, e.g.

```
 <entries>
     …
     <response>                            
         …
         <resData>                         
             …
             <data name="dns">
```

IMO this is easier and more appropriate than having the extra step of copying over the values into an array which would disconnect it from the actual DOM tree and which you would have to repeat for all the elements you want to map this way. XPath is built-in. You just query and get the result.

Because `$dataElements` is an array, you can also access the elements in it individually with

```
echo $dataElements[0]; // prints "ns1.google.com"
echo $dataElements[1]; // prints "ns2.google.com"
```

Note that the `$dataElements` array actually contains [`SimpleXmlElements`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) connected to the main document. Any changes you do to them will also be reflected in the main document.